# Vim Powerline symbol errors (2B80, 2B83, 28(xx), 2B61 etc)

Tags: vim, vim-powerline

Recently I decided to delve into Vim after looking for a new text editor after adopting a Linux distro as a secondary operating system. I've installed Powerline as it seems the norm to do and for about 20 minutes I had it fully working (until I closed Vim), though after that (about a week ago) they failed to appear  again (pretty sure they were just separators, not actual symbols - although that coming from me is entirely unqualified).

I've followed just about every fix I could find under the Sun, followed the documentation on font patching etc, nothing seems to be working.

I'm sure it's a stupidly easy fix and I'm just a bit too dull to find it, but hopefully I can fix it somehow as it's really, really bugging me.

Have a good Christmas!

PS. I just registered (I could've sworn I already had an account though apparently not), so I'm unable to post images. But I'll do my best to explain it: On the left of the status bar you have the mode, then next to that it the first symbol error (again, it might not even be a symbol error, I'm just going off what I think was my issue online), it's a rectangle (portrait) with 2B80 in it, after that there's the filename, and immediately after is the very same rectangle with the same code in it. But there are other errors as stated in the title such as 2B83 and 2B61, as well as just 28.

I'd imagine they are supposed to be separators as they're after every segment of the status bar, but I have no idea. I'm stumped.

Thanks for any/all help!

Comment: Neither powerline nor any of its "lighter" alternative are "the norm". But they certainly are a waste of time considering their almost total lack of usefulness. Read `:help 'statusline'` instead.

Comment: Oh, I didn't by any means mean 'norm' in the sense that 'everyone has it'. I meant it in the sense that it's probably he largest and most well known of all of the statusline plugins. Well, judging from what I've read it seems to be the case.

I'll take  a look now, thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask because general hardware and software questions are on-topic there.

Comment: Cheers, jww. I'll keep that in mind, the issue is solved now though. I think it was the sheer number of similar questions that brought me to this section as opposed to others, apologies about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was following some outdated instructions. This worked fine for me:

- Completely remove anything I'd already done with the modification (a
  fresh start)

> ```
> sudo apt-get install python-pip
> pip install --user git+git://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline
> ```

- Add the following to your .vimrc

> ```
> python from powerline.vim import setup as powerline_setup
> python powerline_setup()
> python del powerline_setup
>
> set laststatus=2
> call vundle#end() (only applicable if you use Vundle)
> ```

- You should then download the latest version of the Powerline Symbols OpenType font (use the commands below)

> ```
> cd ~
> wget https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/raw/develop/font/PowerlineSymbols.otf
> ```

- Move the downloadef file to one of your font directories (either ~/.local/share/fonts/ or ~/usr/local/share/fonts as ~/.fonts is deprecated and won't be used in future versions).

> ```
> mv PowerlineSymbols.otf ~/.local/share/fonts
> ```

- Update your system's font chahe

> sudo fc-cache -f -v

- Download and move the fontconfig file to ~/.fonts.conf

> ```
> wget https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/raw/develop/font/10-powerline-symbols.conf
> ```

- Create a per-user fontconfig folder if it doesn't already exist

> ```
> mkdir -p ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
> mv 10-powerline-symbols.conf ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf/
> ```

Again, this worked for me, can't guarantee that it will for others but it certainly worked charms for me.